# Ubuntu 17.10 login screen wallpaper

Tags: appearance

I like the wallpaper of Ubuntu 17.10 login screen and I would like to set it as my main wallpaper, too. Can you tell me where it is located in my files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it just some tiled colour and texture?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Nautilus** navigate to `/usr/share/backgrounds`:

[image: usr share backgrounds.png]

You will find more images in the subdirectories. For example **gnome** has many wallpapers and yours might be in it.